# I have saved a username and password using the JSP Servlets in user page. But in the login page it does not checks the credentials

Tags: google-chrome, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have an Add user page i.e index.jsp which is having 5 fields: Full name, Student age, Address, User name, Password. And I save the user name and password using JSP servlet i.e Register.java. Then I check the User name and Password in the Login page i.e login.jsp. I have set the attributes in Register.java and check them in login. But the Login page doesn't check the credentials.

I have used an ArrayList and set attributes to it. Then I used HTTP Session to save the details.

```
    ArrayList<String> item=new ArrayList<String>();
    String fullName=request.getParameter("fullName");
    String age=request.getParameter("age")
    String address=request.getParameter("address");
    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
    item.add(fullName);
    item.add(age);
    item.add(address);`
    item.add(username);
    item.add(password);`
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    request.setAttribute("userName",username);
    request.setAttribute("password", password);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

The login must give an error message if someone tries to login with wrong credentials.

Comment: how you are deciding username and passwords are correct or not ? you must compare with database values or static values .right ?

Comment: I don't send the values to the database.

Comment: how you're deciding that username and passwords are valid ?

Comment: I check them in the login servlet using this code,

Comment: PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String usernamePre = request.getParameter("userName");
        String passwordPre = request.getParameter("password");
        String username = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");
        if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(usernamePre) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(passwordPre)) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            writer.write("invalid credentials");
        }

Comment: you're sending both username and password from front end and comparing it 
 with themselves in servlet. that's funny

Comment: I do not use the database for this and all the user names and passwords are checked from the front end.

Comment: You should totally rethink your design. Checking user credentials at the CLIENT side is a massive security hole. Everybody coiuld check out the javascript code in your page and could fake the login.